# Problema en el navegador con el servidor de Angular

Tags: angular, servidor

Hola me aparece esto cada que quiero entrar al servidor de angular que levante. No entiendo porque no me carga y no encuentro respuesta alguna por ningun lado.
Intente poner ng serve de nuevo y me aparece esto:
Node.js version v19.4.0 detected.
Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not be used for production. For more information, please see https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/.
Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace.

De la nada se puso asi y no entiendo porque :([image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola iris camila, bienvenida, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, y adjuntes tu código como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos.
mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla! 
Cuando respondas al comentario de alguien, escribe "@nombreDelQueComento", para que este sea notificado.

Comment: buen dia le distes ng serve a tu aplicacion de angular para que logre correr con su respectiva ubicacion?

Answer (score 0):

con lo que nos muestras, lo que podría ser es tu versión de nodejs bájala a una lts y vuelve a realizar el `ng serve -o`.

Para bajar la versión trabaja con NVM.